# how to stop to use ssl on tuleap 9.1?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, httpd.conf, tuleap

On centos 6, tuleap 9.1, after installation I am only able to access the main page on http, the rest is not available because each links are root on https. Is there's a way to deactivate ssl completely?

I installed all, now can access to the first presentation page, but only if I use http and not https. Problem all the rest of the link of page ( create account, connexion etc...) redirect to https. I already try to deactivate https without success.

Can anyone can help to disable https and is stopping using ssl definitely can generate issue when using this tool?

Answer (score 0):

You could force your website to only load on HTTP through your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

I've included `www` in the Rewrite, if you don't want that then you can remove that section. I've also set `R=302`so that it is a temporary redirect. Set this to `R=301` once you know it is working, as that will make it permanent.

Make sure you clear your cache before you test this.